# How can I organize recovered files into separate folders by file type?

Tags: windows, file, command-line, recovery

I've got 218GB of assorted files recovered from a failing hard drive using PhotoRec. The files do not have their original file names and they're not sorted in any manner.

How can I go about sorting the files into separate folders by file type? I've tried searching for .jpg, for example, and I can copy those results into a new folder. But when I search for something like .txt, I get 16GB of text files as the result and there's no way I've found to select them all and copy them into their own folder. The system just hangs.

This is all being done on Windows 10.

Comment: ---If your files are distributed among many directories, you would need to use a find command. In Linux, this would be quite simple with the command, find. In Windows, I have never tried anything like this. On MSDN there is an article about PowerShell that features an example which seems reminiscient of what you want to do. MSDN Documentation Everything (the windows program) is a godsend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open powershell.  Change to the recovered data folder `cd c:\...\recovered_files`.  Make a directory for the text files `mkdir text_files`.  Do the move `mv *.txt text_files`.

You really just want to move/cut the files like this instead of copying, because moving the files is just a name change (very fast), but to copy would have to duplicate all of the data (quite slow).

If your files are distributed among many directories, you would need to use a find command.  In Linux, this would be quite simple with the command, `find`.  In Windows, I have never tried anything like this.  On MSDN there is an article about PowerShell that features an example which seems reminiscient of what you want to do. [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item#example-4-recursively-move-all-files-of-a-specified-extension-from-the-current-directory-to-another-directory)

The gist of it is that you would use the command:

```
cd <your recovered files directory containing the recup_dir folders>
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.txt" -Recurse | Move-Item -Verbose -Destination "Z:\stock_recovered\TXT"
```

Note that the destination is outside of the search path, which might be important!

Since I have never tried this before, there is **NO WARRANTY**.  Supposing it works, I would be curious to know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, moving is what I want to do. I tried the command as you wrote it, and it works for the individual subfolder that I enter in. Is there any way for it to find any .txt in any of its subfolders as well?

So, I have powershell looking at this directory: Z:\stock_recovered\recovered_files\recup_dir.1

And I use this command to move any .txt to the TXT folder I made:
mv *.txt Z:\stock_recovered\TXT

That works fine, but there are over 11,000 recup_dir.* subfolders. Is there a way to have the move command look for .txt files in all of the subfolders as well?

Comment: Beautiful! I tested it on a smaller scale and it works perfectly!

Comment: Good to hear.  I hope your recovery goes well, it sounds like a disaster!

Comment: Yeah, it's a sudden drive failure (from a relative) and they didn't have a backup.

By the way, this is still running (4hrs) and I'm realizing it'd be nice to have a readout of some sort. How could I change the command to show the overall status or what is currently being moved?

Comment: Using the disk io meter in resource monitor might be reassuring!  Measuring the size of the destination folder might be helpful too.  The ship had probably sailed on a verbose option unless you want to restart it...

Comment: I just finished up. Now, I'll be running this for several different extension types, so it could be handy for those.

Comment: You can add -Verbose after move-item (answer updated).  If you have lots of small files, outputting that data might make the copy take significantly longer though.